# Laravel 5.4 can't get relation of elloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, relationship

I have filters which belong to filter groups
Filter.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Filter extends Model
{
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\FilterGroup');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_filters');
    }

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Filter', 'category_filter');
    }
}
```

And categories which have many to many relationship with the filters
Category.php:

```
namespace App;

use App\Events\CategoryDelete;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $events = [
        'deleting' => CategoryDelete::class
    ];

    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'parent_id');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        $parentCategories = collect([]);

        $parent = $this->parent;

        while (!is_null($parent)) {
            $parentCategories[] = $parent;

            $parent = $parent->parent;
        }

        return $parentCategories->reverse();
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Filter', 'category_filter');
    }

    public function hasFilter($filter_id)
    {
        foreach ($this->filters as $filter) {
            if ($filter->id == $filter_id) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function getFilterGroups()
    {
        $filterGroups = collect([]);

        foreach ($this->filters as $filter) {
            if (!$filterGroups->has($filter->group->id)) {
                $filterGroups[$filter->group->id] = $filter->group;
            }
        }

        return $filterGroups;
    }
}
```

And in the category view I want to display the filters along with their filter group but when I try the following:

```
@foreach($category->filters as $filter)
    {{ $filter->group->name }}
    <br>
@endforeach
```

It throws the **Trying to get property of non-object** exception
Why can't I get the group of the filter?

Comment: There's 2 options how this could happen: 1) One of the filters you're iterating through does not have a group. 2) Your relationship is not set up correctly

Comment: Category doesn't seems to have `filters` relation defined in the model

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva it's the 5th method down :)

Comment: @RossWilson Oops! my bad... forgot to scroll down the code.

Comment: What property/object is mentioned in the error?

Comment: The relationship seems fine... I think a filter is missing group and it is causing this issue. You need to check first if group exists for the filter and then try to access its name.

Comment: @RossWilson the exception is "Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\ecommerce-system\resources\views\category.blade.php)" no object is mentioned
But I've done a debug and figured out that it is thrown when I try to access $filter->group

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva the structrue of my does not allow a filter to exist without having a group. I checked my database and everything there seems fine. But $filter-group returns null

Comment: @TheAngelM97 did you use tinker to debug the category for which filters needs to be shown?

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva no I just used dd($filter->group)

Comment: @TheAngelM97 ok... if you could just dd `$category->filters` to check the filters it is associated with and verify for their groups. I'm unsure about `group` being a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the group() method inside the Filter model to filterGroup and now when I call $filter->filterGroup it works fine. I dont know why, maybe group is some reserved word or something.